# VBA macro runs on one computer but not on the other

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I have a macro that runs fine on my computer, but when I put this macro on another computer it does not even allow to run in debug mode. It just crashes the MS Project saying that it stopped working.

Edit:
The crash comes from the following `Set`. I have already tried early binding as well `Dim xlApp as Excel.Application` but crashes anyway.

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
```

is there another way to set the xlApp as an Excel object?

Comment: OS on both computers? Office versions on both computers?

Comment: Same version of MS Project on each computer?

Comment: Yes, same OS and MS Project. The only thing that differs is Excel, which I use the library in the code, but I am referencing it right in both computers.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm afraid of sharing confidential data. I've edited the post as I managed to go into debug mode when commenting out the `Set xlApp`

Comment: From the little you've given us I'd reckon you want to use late binding rather than early binding.

Comment: What is the Error Message that you Received ? Just Crashed saying that it stopped working?

Comment: I've tried early binding `Dim xlApp as Excel.Application` and crashes as well. @Sid29 Yes, just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Try late binding the Excel object and remove the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Late Binding.  As @Josh said - you'll need to remove  your library references and update a substantial portion of your code.

Any constants that are specific to Excel will need updating to their numerical equivalent.
For example, when using `PasteSpecial` you'd use something like `xlPasteValues`.
Open the immediate window in Excel and enter `?xlPasteValues`.  This will return `-4163` which is the number you must enter into your code in place of `xlPasteValues`.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWrkBk As Object
    Dim oWrkSht As Object

    Set oXL = CreateXL
    Set oWrkBk = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Workbook1.xlsx")
    Set oWrkSht = oWrkBk.worksheets("Sheet1")

    With oWrkSht
        .Range("A1").Copy
        .Range("B1").PasteSpecial -4163 'xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub

Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this, just to see if it also crashes.

it creates the word object, then excel object and exits. each time it creates the object, it dispays the object name.

i am assuming that you also have msword installed

note: if you ever copy code from a web page, make sure that the quotation marks are correct. there appear to be several versions of quotation marks (opening quotes, closing quotes), and these are not valid in VBA

```
Sub test()

    Dim myApp As Object
    Set myApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    MsgBox myApp.Name

    Set myApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    MsgBox myApp.Name

    Set myApp = Nothing

End Sub
```